# Is there a way to check if any of values (previous and current) are the same in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation

So I have 3 input fields which could contain 3 similar values, but I need that data to be unique for each field.

```
            {productFormData.Roles.map((role: string, index: number) => {
              return (
                <div className={`form-group input-buyer-${index}`} key={index}>
                  <Input
                    name={`role-${index}`}
                    type={"text"}
                    id={`buyer-role-${index}`}
                    placeholder={rolesPlaceHolderList[index]}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      setProductFormData({
                        ...productFormData,
                        Roles: productFormData.Roles.map(
                          (item: string, i: number) => {
                            if (
                              !productFormData.Roles.includes(
                                event.target.value
                              )
                            ) {
                              setUsersUnique(false);
                            } else {
                              setUsersUnique(true);
                            }
                            if (index == i) return event.target.value;
                            return item;
                          }
                        ),
                      })
                    }
                    label={`${roleLabels[index]} [Required]`}
                    value={role}
                  />
                  {simpleValidator.current.message(
                    `${personasErrorLabels[index]}`,
                    role.trim(),
                    `required|min:2|max:250`
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

**setUsersUnique** is a React State which validates uniqueness, for now it works but is dependant on the order of entering data into inputs, which is not exactly what I want.

I expect to **usersUnique** state to be true while **every one of 3 inputs** has unique values.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    simpleValidator.current.allValid() && !summaryValidation && !usersUnique
      ? setBtnDisabled(false)
      : setBtnDisabled(true);

  });
```

Right now I am validating based on button state with useEffect().

Comment: In the title you want to check 2 values(prev and current), but the description said there are 3 values?

Comment: 3 separate input fields - [x, y, z] these values cant repeat at any point

Comment: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) will be helpful

Comment: Or you can directly write `x != y && y != z && x != z`, it's easy to understand. `new Set([x, y, z]).size === 3` is the code using Set

Comment: you can grap one value of any input, and then loop through them with method `some()` (except input you grapped)
if one of element has the same value of input which we grapped at first, so no uniqueness

Comment: One more thing, is there a way to exclude whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve that problem with this code

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const formRoles = productFormData.Roles;
    const setRoles = Array.from(new Set(formRoles));
    if (setRoles.length < 3) setBtnDisabled(true);
  });
```

My validation rules are there should always be 3 Roles provided by user so that validation with **Set** usage is allowed and simple.

Because I've used **Set** collection if any value is repeated in that input **setRoles** will have unwanted amount of values and disable my Submit button.